# Как исправить ошибку с запуском Munin на Debian 8?

Tags: linux, debian

Столкнулся со следующей проблемой, после установки пакета Munin на Debian 8 он не запускается, пишет:

> Failed to start munin.service: Unit munin.service is masked

Как можно решить проблему?

P.S. Снятие маски (systemctl unmask munin.service) не помогает, в списке юнитов (systemctl list-unit-files) сервис все равно виден как masked. Хотя munin-node отображается как enabled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как оказалось, это его нормальное состояние (ввела в заблуждение работа с предыдущими версиями munin на debian, где сервис был active).